# Is it safe to `.clone()` Pool of `diesel_async` across threads?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, rust-diesel, rust-axum

I am using [`diesel_async`](https://github.com/weiznich/diesel_async).

Let's say I have connections in deadpool.
I want total `deadpool_max_size` connections.

```rs
let pool: Pool<AsyncPgConnection> = Pool::builder(deadpool_config)
    .max_size(deadpool_max_size)
    .build()
    .unwrap();
```

And I have to share the pool across multiple arbitrary number of async threads.

```rs
// share the pool with async thread
let _pool = pool.clone();
tokio::spawn(async move { 
    let mut conn = _pool.get().await.unwrap();
    // ... using conn
});

// and another different async thread
let _pool = pool.clone();
tokio::spawn(async move { 
    let mut conn = _pool.get().await.unwrap();
    // ... using conn
});
 
// and so on...
// let _pool = pool.clone(); 
// tokio::spawn(async move { .......
```

I want the number of connections the entire rust program generates in total must be less than or equal to `deadpool_max_size` at any time.

In the example above, I didn't wrapped the pool with `Arc`, `Mutex`, or `RwLock`.
But just used the pure `.clone()` directly.
The reason was that I saw there's already `Arc` field in the type.

Is this example suitable to satisfy my intention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally in Rust, if something can't be shared across threads, the compiler will prevent you from doing that.

In this case, [`Pool`](https://docs.rs/deadpool/0.9.5/deadpool/managed/struct.Pool.html) is both `Send + Sync`, so it is safe to share across threads. [It also wraps an `Arc` internally](https://docs.rs/deadpool/0.9.5/src/deadpool/managed/mod.rs.html#265), so it is cheap to clone and you don't need your own `Arc`.

[This is even documented](https://docs.rs/deadpool/0.9.5/deadpool/managed/struct.Pool.html):

> This struct can be cloned and transferred across thread boundaries and uses reference counting for its internal state.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. I actually thought the same from your answer but the reason I wrote the question is something strange happens. Would you come and see this as well?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77394594/connection-pools-connection-is-droped-in-rust-so-unable-to-use